# Please correct me on this,its very confusing

Tags: java, reflection

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.
I have been taught,that

1. Every time a class is loaded, a class object is created in heap memory,and its reference by the name of Class is kept in class area
2. Each and every field,like string,int whatsoever is the is also stored in as objects and its reference is given in class object created
3. Same goes for method,constructor's etc

now there is a question also,whether all these thing is stored for every object or just one object is created to know about the information

Also do tell me What does this Field class in actual have? like for eg

```
class b
{
String s="sdnla";
}
```

and there are two objects of b class,b1 and b2,what does Field class  object have?

Comment: If you are talking about `Class<?>`, all of them are singletons; only one ever exists at runtime (per classloader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal circumstances, there is just one Class object per class. Not per object. If Java created all that structure for every object, it would use enormous amounts of memory; far more than is actually needed.

If you are creating multiple classloaders within your application, then you may end up with multiple Class objects per class - one held by each classloader.  But very few of us ever do such a thing.  You might do this if you were programming an application server, or something of that type.

Comment: per class _and_ classloader; a same classloader can load the same class twice, creating another such `Class<?>`. But you don't play with classloaders that much... Except if you program an app server or the like

Comment: Right. If you have multiple classloaders, you can get multiple copies of a class.  Of course, this isn't a common situation.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Normaly the non static field are stored for every object created. So how we differentiate the value of every objects? Mthods are stored once.

Comment: Yes, @user230137, what you are saying is that there is one object per object.  Nobody is disputing this.

Comment: Please also answer my field question,what does the Filed class have?is is different for every object?

Comment: No, you don't have a new Field instance per object.  It doesn't actually store the values for each object, so only one Field (per field) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

the variables in the class are initialized for every object
separate space is allocated for it
but for constructor and methods there is only one common space allocated
and all the objects of the class reference this

Answer (score 0):

If i properly understood your question. Please think about String pool in that situation. I think both s references might point to the same reference on the string pool no matter how many object you will create.

> String pool is a special storage area in Java heap, mostly located on
>   PerGen space, to store String literals like "abc". When Java program
>   creates a new String using String literal, JVM checks for that String
>   in pool and if String literal is already present in pool than same
>   object is returned instead of creating a whole new object. String pool
>   check is only performed when you create String as literal, if you
>   create String using new() operator, a new String object will be
>   created even if String with same content is available in pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with older block-structured languages, an Object instance is conceptually a Structure plus a pointer to the Class which that Object is an instance of. The Class provides the methods, the static fields, and anything else which is shared across all its instances (directly or via a pointer to the resource in question). The Object carries the non-static fields.